# How do I sync Google Photos to a hard drive directory?

Tags: nautilus, online-accounts, google-drive

I take pictures on my Android phone, and I have them synced with Google Photos, which puts them on other devices immediately via the cloud.

How do I enable Google Photos to automatically sync to my Ubuntu laptop hard drive?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: @N0rbert I'm on Unity+Plank (budgie hybrid) DE Ubuntu 18.10 but will be 19.04 shortly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must check the box to [enable](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0) *Google Photos* folder in your *Google Drive* settings so that your Photos will be visible in Drive.

A standard Ubuntu install has GNOME settings has a built in "Online Accounts" section to easily configure a drive in to show in nautilus File Viewer.

You also have a few options to mimic the behavior of Dropbox clients there's [OverGrive](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu) and [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) but I prefer to not have the files stored locally and for that I use [Ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse).

**Ocamlfuse**

The [creator made a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~alessandro-strada/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for it with .deb files for Ubunutu, run the following in a terminal to install the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

Then, still in the terminal, run the following to get started:

`google-drive-ocamlfuse`

This will set up the configuration files and folders needed as well as launch your default browser so you can login to your google account.

Next, back in the terminal, you will need to create a directory to mount your google drive in:

`mkdir ~/googledrive`

And finally to mount the drive so you can see your files, run:

`google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/googledrive`

It works similarly to nfs in that the files aren't actually copied to your computer so if you want to have them when you aren't connected to the internet, you will need to copy them to a local directory.

Comment: Does this work with Google *Photos* (what was asked) or Google *Drive*?

Comment: ocamlfuse is a good solution for mounting google-drive but to sync your drive to your local hard drive in the way that dropbox works, you will need to sync the drives using something like opendrive see attached link: https://linoxide.com/tools/how-use-google-drive-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: In my tests, it seems like `ocamlfuse` performs twice as fast in transfers as the built in `"Online Accounts" GNOME feature`, BUT it also doesn't report any progress to nautilus during mid-file transfer yet

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Jonathan. I completely forgot.

Answer (score 7):

[This other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138468/2355) will not work. Google stopped syncing Google photo with Google Drive awhile ago.

If you want access to Google Drive then the above works great. If you want to mount Google Photo then there does not seem to be a solution.

This program is useful for backing up and keeping in sync with Google Photo

https://pypi.org/project/gphotos-sync/

Answer (score 1):

### I use gphotos-sync and it's painless after setup.

### Mind that gphotos-sync only downloads your photos, it cannot upload!!

You need to configure google-photos sharing in the google-cloud before use:

Use these guides:

Use these guides:

- https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Local_incremental_Google_Photos_backup_on_Ubuntu.html
- or https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ck1679H8ifmZ_4eVbDeD_-jezIcZ-j6MlaNaeQiz7y0/edit

When you're ready, go to:

https://console.cloud.google.com/

Create a new project. Name and location don't matter.

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/apis/library, select your new project, then select the Photos Library API. Click the big blue Enable button.

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis, select your project and go to OAuth Consent Screen. Select External.

Fill in a name and click Save.

In the menu bar, go to Credentials, Create Credentials, OAuth ClientID.

Select type Desktop Application and give the client a name. I used gp_client.

You'll see a confirmation screen. Afterwards, use the download arrow button to save the file as `client_secret.json`:

[image]

I saved it in my `~/Downloads` folder and then moved it to the correct folder for gphotos-sync, creating it if it does not exist:

the `client_secret.json` file has to be named as here.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gphotos-sync/
cp ~/Downloads/client_secret.json ~/.config/gphotos-sync/client_secret.json
```

Once you log in to Google you might get an 'Unverified' warning, which, in this case, is fine.

After this, rather complex process, it's time to install and then you can start using the software.

```
python -m pip install --user gphotos-sync
gphotos-sync YOUR-DIRECTORY
```

If you get an error when trying to sync then use this:

```
gphotos-sync --new-token YOUR-DIRECTORY
```

Here you have it on github:

https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync/

https://github.com/somethingSomething78/gphotos-sync

Comment: According to the links, this cannot upload photos, only download them. https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Local_incremental_Google_Photos_backup_on_Ubuntu.htm " It cannot upload photos to Google Photos."  So not really a sync, just an auto downloader.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes I knew that but forgot to mention it, added!